# mysql data dump formatting

Tags: mysql

I have been tasked with creating a .sql batch file to query a MySQL database (version: 4.1.13-standard) containing user/server/group information, ex.

user1   server1 group1,group2

user1   server2 group1,group3

user1   server3 group5

user2   server2 group2

user2   server5 group2

user3   server4 group4

The trick is, the output file must be formatted in such a way that there is one line per user with all the server and group information combined.  So the example above would look like:

"user1","server1:group1-group2;server2:group1-group3;server1:group5"

"user2","server2:group2;server5:group2"

"user3","server4:group4"

I apologize if this or a similar question has been answered before.  I promise I spent hours searching for a solution but did not find one.  Or I didn't realize it when I saw it.  By trade, I am not a DBA by any stretch of the imagination, and what little I do know about mysql isn't enough to figure this out.

So far, the closest I've gotten is using:

```
select concat(name,',',group_concat(concat(trim(hostname),':',replace(trim(groups),',','-'))separator ';'))
```

Thanks for any help you wish to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a little bit around with one of my databases and I got a result with is rather similar to your expected result, because I've no database that is structurde like yours.

Try

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  t.name, ',', GROUP_CONCAT(
      DISTINCT CONCAT(TRIM(t.hostname),':', REPLACE(TRIM(t.groups),',','-'))
  SEPARATOR ';')
) FROM table_name t GROUP BY t.name
```

I guess, DISTINCT and GROUP BY t.name could be the magic words ;)

Comment: klausinho, GROUP BY is definitely the magic words!  And DISTINCT probably doesn't hurt either.  Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Yor're welcome! I got so many solutions and good ideas from this community that I'm lucky to pay a little back